# Why my program not executed before my page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a JavaScript program after I press my enter key, it will finish executing the program then my page will refresh. I try to add an if loop inside my last function but it not working.

I'm really new to HTML CSS and JavaScript.

The bottom will be my program:

```js
var move = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 97) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
      }, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
      }, 2000);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 98) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
      }, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
      }, 2000);
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 99) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      appDiv.classList.add("robot2_end_left");
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 100) {
      const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_left");
    }

      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
        setTimeout(function() {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function() {
          appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
        }, 0);

         setTimeout(window.location.reload(true), 0);
      }

  }
```

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("TPHRG floorplan1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* background-position: center; */
    background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
  }

  .robot_start_top {
    top: 280px;
    transition: top 2s;
  }

  .robot_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 600px;
    transition: all 2s;
  }

  .robot_end_left {
    left: 570px;
  }

  .robot_end_top {
    top: 180px;
  }

  .robot1_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 570px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot1_end_left {
    left: 520px;
  }

  .robot2_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 520px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot2_end_left {
    left: 470px;
  }
  .robot3_start_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 470px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot3_end_left {
    left: 420px;
  }

  .robot3_start_right {
    position: fixed;
    left: 470px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }
  .robot3_start_down {
    position: fixed;
    left: 180px;
    transition: left 4s;
  }

  .robot3_end_down {
    top: 280px;
  }

  .robot3_end_right {
    left: 570px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body onkeydown="move(event)">
    <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
      <img id="robot" style= width:30px; height:40px" src="pic_8.PNG">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean "if loop" or "if condition"?

Comment: sorry what do you mean? What I wanted is getting my page refresh after my keycode 13 function is finish. Hope you able to help me with it

Comment: i was refering to the misconception in your post. Your question already has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload(true), 0);
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. It will reload immediately, rendering the `setTimeout` useless.

Try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, 0);
```

Or this, if you can use arrow functions:

```
setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(true), 0);
```

Comment: I try this, but it still refreshes before my program is executed

Comment: you are trying to execute the function in 0 milliseconds then it will execute as soon as you press enter key you code is doing what you instructed it to do. Can you try increasing the time in setTimeOut?

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation gave me a better understanding.